# У Лео и Констанции родился ребёнок(,) больной ВИЧом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

Нужна запятая?

*У Лео и Констанции родился ребёнок(,) больной ВИЧом.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна:

*У Лео и Констанции родился ребёнок, больной ВИЧом*.

Нет оснований не ставить. Определительный оборот обособляется по обычным правилам. Существительное не нуждается в этом определении, а оно само смысловым центром не является.

Comment: Но тут же главное — болезненность ВИЧом!

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Всë же таки я бы обособил. Можно обособлять, даже если, как говорила Sharon, нельзя убрать по смыслу.

Comment: Sharon говорит, что в этой грамматической модели (согласованное определение) нельзя сделать это определение центром высказывания. Используйте несогласованное определение, тогда на него буде падать ударение без обособления. Или так: У них ребенок родился больнЫм, с ВИЧ-инфекцией.  И т. д. Для заданного содержания подбирайте подходящую модель.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно так:
*У Лео и Констанции родился ребёнок с ВИЧ-инфекцией.*

ВИЧ – это не болезнь, а вирус. Им заражаются, с ним рождаются.

Comment: Фу! Никакого изменения!

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр  Попрошу не выражаться.  "Фу" относится в первую очередь к вашему вопросу. Посмотрели бы для начала, что такое ВИЧ, СПИД. К тому же ВИЧ не склоняется.

Comment: Почему не склоняется? К аббревиатурам можно приделывать падежные окончания. В Википедии написаны все падежи слова _ВИЧ_.

Comment: @Максим Вот, например, из Википедии: ...*клетки, которые могут быть заражены ВИЧ*. Но Википедия вообще не показатель. Да, некоторые звуковые аббревиатуры склоняются: ВАК, ГОСТ, МХАТ, ВГИК, ТЮЗ, СПИД, ОМОН. Прочие в письменной речи не склоняются. Конечно, в разговорной речи склонение возможно: *пробка на МКАДе, сотрудник ЗАГСа*. Это взято с Грамоты.  Тогда уж не ВИЧом, а ВИЧем.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Допустим, склонять можно. (Имеется в виду _если_.) Тогда почему _ВИЧем_, а не _ВИЧом_? Википедия с буквой О пишет. Википедия не всë показывает, согласен, но почему ьуква Е, а не О? Я с вами не спорю, а спрашиваю, как вы это объясните.

Comment: @Максим Не знаю, интуитивно, потом посмотрю, щас некада.

Comment: ВИЧом? Это ударное окончание. Звучит изумительно. Сленг, наверное.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Непонятен ваш комментарий. Так вы хотите изменений? Ну я и изменил предложение. Можно убрать "инфекцию", это не принципиально. Но в любом случаем ВИЧом не болеют.