# Обособление согласованных определений (три примера)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, определения

**Нужна запятая?**  Как объяснить?

(1)  *Это неудачное предложение!   Нужно придумать предложение(?)  **простое и понятное.***

(2) *Это неудачное предложение!  Нужно придумать предложение(?)  **простое и понятное всем.***

(3) *Это неудачное предложение!  Нужно придумать предложение(?)  **простое и всем понятное.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня получается так:

*Это неудачное предложение! Нужно придумать предложение прост**О**е и пон**Я**тное.*

*Это неудачное предложение! Нужно придумать предлож**Е**ние, / простое и понятное вс**Е**м.*

*Это неудачное предложение! Нужно придумать предложение прост**О**е / и всем пон**Я**тное.*

Объяснение в [**вашем ответе**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476644/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87/476697#476697).

Comment: Да, верно. Здесь интересный момент. Дополнение ВСЕМ после определения перетягивает ударение на себя, но этого нет в позиции перед определением. Небольшой нюанс, а пунктуация меняется. Увидеть это может не каждый)  Точно говорят, что мастерство в нюансах.  Написать реалистическую картину могут многие, но "оживить" ее может только мастер.  И так во всяком деле.

Answer (score 0):

Обособление здесь, по **[2-му пункту (2)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=108)**, не нужно.

*Это неудачное предложение! Нужно придумать предложение **простое и понятное***;

*Это неудачное предложение! Нужно придумать предложение **простое и понятное всем***;

*Это неудачное предложение! Нужно придумать предложение **простое и всем понятное***.

Посмотрите внимательно на примеры в справочнике в пункте 2-2 и сравните. Состыкуется буквально всë.

Comment: Мне думается, что не все.  А вы еще подумайте))  Ударения и паузы посмотрите.

Comment: Ударения также совпадают. Как в справочнике, так и збесь ударения падают на определительный оборот.

Comment: Вы не справочнику объясните, а по сути. Что значит: падает на оборот? В обороте несколько слов. К примеру, я вам скажу: нет основний не ставить запятую в этом предложении. А вы мне что ответите? Вы же Лео так отвечали. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476635/У-Лео-и-Констанции-родился-ребёнок-больной-ВИЧом

Comment: @Sharon Александр тоже так отвечал. Просто Лео принимает отвнт, даже если ссылки на источник ты не даéшь. Просто напишешь: «Запятая нужна» — и Лео примит. Но я всегда стараюсь делать всë в соответствии с правилами и в ответе указывать всë необходимое. А этот ответ пока оставлю. Это моë мнение, а прислушиваться к ниму или нет — ваше право. В любом случае я делал всë в соответствии с правилами и указал хороший вариант. В любом случае я не считаю нужным ставить запятую, интонация — подтверждение. Может, потом дополню ответ, а пока так.

Comment: Да, Лео так принимает, но это не есть хорошо. Я прислушиваюсь к вашему мнению. Думается мне, то мы не все еще обсудили в этой теме. А если так: Это неудачное предложение! Нужно придумать предложение простое и понятное каждому из нас. Будем или не будем обособлять? Почему?